# Como posso criar várias $_SESSION em uma unica função?

Tags: php, html, css, sql

Para ser mais claro, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em PHP e SQL simples, que tem quebrado minha cabeça nos ultimos dias...

```html
<?php
session_start();

    include 'header.php';

    include 'db.php';

    $pesquisa = isset($_POST['busca']) ? $_POST['busca'] : '';
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nome LIKE '%$pesquisa%'";
    $con = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die($mysqli->error);
?>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                <h3>CLIENTES</h3></div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                <?php while ($dados = $con->fetch_array()) { ?>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img src="clientes/<?php echo $dados["foto"] ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="client" style="width: 350px; height: 300px;">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $dados['nome'] ?></h5>
                                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $dados['telefone'] ?></p>
                                <p class="card-text">Cliente nº<?php echo $dados['id']; 
                                $_SESSION["ID"] = $dados['id']; ?></p>
                                <a href="teste.php" class="btn btn-primary">Ler Mais</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

essa é a pagina onde ele exibe o conteúdo no meu banco de dados SQL. Tudo corre bem, até o momento em que eu preciso abrir em outra página apenas o conteudo referente a um ID unico, como a SESSION que criei ali. Porém, apesar de dentro de uma estrutura de repetição, aquela vaiavel $_SESSION só reconhece o primeiro ID.

```html
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';
 $id = $_SESSION["ID"];
 $consulta = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id = '$id'";
    $con = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die($mysqli->error);

    while($dados = $con->fetch_array()){
     echo $dados = $dados['id'];

    
    }


?>
```

E sempre que tento buscar essa super global aqui nessa pagina de teste, ela me retorna o mesmo resultado, que sempre é o primeiro dado inserido no banco, não importa quantos eu coloque. Alguém por favor me da uma luz pra sair desse impasse?

Comment: tem algumas coisas aqui para comentar: 1) session dentro de um `while`: a session vai guardar só o último (cada iteração do while vai sobrescrever o valor anteior) valor do `while`, então isso está sem sentido, a não ser que guardade um array de valores. 2) fez um `select` com `like` que pode retornar mais de um registro, então o jeito que usou a session não faz sentido, deveria ser um array. 3)na segunda página, se é uma consulta por id único como disseste, então só vai retornar um valor, o q talvez seja o que quiz dizer com "*retorna o mesmo resultado*", então o comportamento está certo.

Comment: ```echo $dados = $dados['id'];``` isso vai retornar só id ficando só com 1 elemento "que sempre é o primeiro dado inserido no banco"